# Where are the Build and Src locations for QtCreator?

Tags: programming, plugins, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator

In the QtCreator Plugin Creation Wizard, this
http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-extending/images/firstplugin-pluginsetup.png
 window asks for Qt Creator Sources, and Qt Creator Build.

I installed the Ubuntu SDK from the Repos, and am perplexed where to find these folders. The wizard will not let me move on until I find them.

Tutorial:
http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-extending/first-plugin.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you'll need the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install qtcreator-dev  qtxmlpatterns5-dev-tools
```

Start a new Project in Qt Creator (**Libraries** -> **Qt Creator Plugin**)

[image]

Give it a **name**:

[image]

Confirm the **Kit Selection**:

[image]

Use `/usr/src/qtcreator` for **Qt Creator sources** and `/tmp` for **Qt Creator build** and deploy in **Local user settings**. Click **Next**:

[image]

Finally click on **Finish** to complete the wizard:

[image]

You should now see your plugins files, open the project file now (*.pro):

[image]

Add the following lines to your .pro file:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator \
        -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/plugins/QtProject
```

[image]

Save the project file and build your Qt Creator plugin:

[image]

You now have your plugin files in your `$HOME/.local/share` folder:

[image]

*(Tested on 14.04 64 bits)*

Comment: Great Work. I made it on through, but now it is asking me for the executable. Which one should I be using?

Comment: Sorry for asking this, but could you please open a new question? 1) I'm not sure to understand what's the executable in your case 2) A detailed error msg and/or a screenshot would help.

Comment: Mmmm... yah; my SDK is a bit fanjangled. After trying to recreate the plugin, the steps are not working anymore. ~:/ I'm sure its something on my side

Comment: Ah I see; One does not run; you build, then relaunch Ubuntu SDK and Pair Programming will be available in the menu.